# How to set user inputs to my properties on WIX installer

Tags: wix

Using WiX I am installing network printer.

My code is as follows:

**Make some properties:**

```
<Property Id='IpAddress' Value='10.2.17.12' />
<Property Id='PortName' Value='MY_TCP_PORT' />
<Property Id='DeviceName' Value='MY PRINTER'/>
```

**Run command using custom action:**
Note that these commands use my property values.

```
<CustomAction Id='CreatePort' Directory='TARGETDIR' Execute='deferred' ExeCommand='cscript c:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prnport.vbs -a -r [PortName] -h [IpAddress] -o raw' Return='check'  Impersonate="no"/>

<CustomAction Id='InstallnetworkPrinter' Directory='TARGETDIR' Execute='deferred' ExeCommand='rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /if /b "[DeviceName]" /f "[PrinterFolder]SIELPRNDRV.inf" /r [PortName] /m "[DeviceName]" /z' Return='check'/>
```

This works fine, but I need to use the user's input value for IPaddress, PortName, and DeviceName. I have made a dialog to input those values.

The controls are as follows:

```
<Control Id ="IPAddress" Type="Edit" Property="IpAddress" X="150" Y="60" Width="100" Height="17" />
<Control Id ="PortName" Type="Edit" Property="PortName" X="150" Y="80" Width="100" Height="17" />
<Control Id="DeviceName" Property="DeviceName" Type="Edit" X="120" Y="69" Width="170" Height="17" Hidden="yes" />
```

The values are not applied as I expect.

What have I missed here?
How can I set user inputs to my properties?

Comment: Try changing the property names so that they are all in capitals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties which you wish to use or set externally, such as from a command line argument, or across different WiX source files, must have a name which is entirely in uppercase.